# Problem converting HTML with Japanese character To PDF using java with YaHP Html to Pdf Converter

Tags: java, html, pdf, converters

I'm trying to convert html string with Japanese character to PDF using YaHP Html to Pdf Converter.

I am using Eclipse Photon Release (4.8.0)

Here is my main class that invokes the YaHP Html :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    String pdfOutFileName = "C:\\test\\JP-Test.pdf";
    double pageHeight = 80;
    String htmlContent = "<html>\r\n" + 
            "   <head>\r\n" + 
            "       <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\r\n" + 
            "           <style type=\"text/css\">\r\n" + 
            "               span.cls_005hr{font-family:Arial,serif;font-size:16.8px;color:rgb(50,50,50);font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration: none}\r\n" + 
            "               div.cls_005hr{font-family:Arial,serif;font-size:14.8px;color:rgb(50,50,50);font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;text-decoration: none}\r\n" + 
            "           </style>\r\n" + 
            "       </head>\r\n" + 
            "       <body>\r\n" + 
            "                   <table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=720>\r\n" + 
            "                    <col width=10 >\r\n" + 
            "                    <col width=710 >\r\n" + 
            "                    <tr>\r\n" + 
            "                     <td valign=\"middle\" height=\"80\" bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\r\n" + 
            "                       <div><span class=\"cls_005hr\">JPTesting</span></div>\r\n" + 
            "                     </td>\r\n" + 
            "                     <td valign=\"middle\" height=\"80\" bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\r\n" + 
            "                       <div><span class=\"cls_005hr\">株式会社　ビー・エス・デーインフォメーションテクノロジー</span></div>\r\n" + 
            "                     </td>\r\n" + 
            "                   </span>\r\n" + 
            "                    </tr>\r\n" + 
            "                   </table>\r\n" + 
            "       </body>\r\n" + 
            "</html>";
    
    System.out.println("htmlContent: [" + htmlContent + "]");

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outFormPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        outFormPDF = PDFUtil.convertHtmlToPDF(htmlContent, pageHeight);
        byte[] bOutFormPDF = outFormPDF.toByteArray();
        
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(pdfOutFileName);
        os.write(bOutFormPDF);
        System.out.println("Successfully Finished writing PDF to output file");
        os.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

and here is the PDFUtil class method that calls YaHP Converter

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream convertHtmlToPDF (String htmlContent, double pageHeight) throws CConvertException, IOException {

    ByteArrayOutputStream outFormPDF = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(htmlContent).useDelimiter("\\Z");
    String htmlContents = scanner.next();

    CYaHPConverter converter = new CYaHPConverter();
    Map properties = new HashMap();
    List headerFooterList = new ArrayList();
    
    URL resource = PDFUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fonts");
    
    String fontDirectory = resource.getPath() ;

    properties.put(IHtmlToPdfTransformer.PDF_RENDERER_CLASS, IHtmlToPdfTransformer.FLYINGSAUCER_PDF_RENDERER);
    properties.put(IHtmlToPdfTransformer.FOP_TTF_FONT_PATH, fontDirectory);
    
    PageSize pageSize = IHtmlToPdfTransformer.LEGALP;

    if (pageHeight>0) {
        String sHeight = Double.toString(pageHeight);
        sHeight = sHeight.substring(0,sHeight.indexOf("."));
        pageHeight = Double.parseDouble(sHeight);
        System.out.println ("pageHeight : " + pageHeight);
        pageSize = new PageSize(21.6d, pageHeight, 0.7d, 0.5d, 1.5d, 1.5d);
    }
            
    System.out.println ("Calling converter.convertToPdf");
    converter.convertToPdf(htmlContents, 
               pageSize, 
               headerFooterList,
               "file://tmp/Html2PdfConvertTemp",
               outFormPDF,
               properties);

    System.out.println ("Successfully Called converter.convertToPdf");
    scanner.close();
    
    return outFormPDF;
}
```

For some reason, the output PDF file contains "JPTesting", but does not contain the Japanese letters :  "株式会社　ビー・エス・デーインフォメーションテクノロジー" .

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a font with those Japanese glyphs actually in it?

Comment: I have a separate directory where I have list of fonts.  I do not have Japanese fonts in it.  Any idea where I can download them or how I can add them?

Comment: I'm afraid not. I'm pretty sure you will find free fonts with those glyphs in them though

Comment: Found the solution.   Posting my solution here in case anyone else may struggle with the same issue that I had.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.   Posting my solution here in case anyone else may struggle with the same issue that I had.

I have added Japanese font from google :  https://fonts.google.com/?subset=japanese  (I Picked Shippori Mincho B1), added to my font resource directory.

Updated my html CSS to pick up those new fonts :
span.cls_005jp{font-family:Shippori Mincho B1, Arial,serif;...

Update my html to use those new fonts for tags that may contain Japanese letters :

株式会社　ビー・エス・デーインフォメーションテクノロジー\r\n"

Thank you, @g00se, for pointing me to the right direction!